# how can i create a setup file for msi

Tags: c#, windows-installer

can I create an setup file that extracts an msi file to a temporary directory and runs it with options same or similar as were passed for the msi file?

The command line option is

```
msiexec /i "path of msi file" /qn
```

Comment: What you want, is not very clear, be more precis

Comment: i want to merge a batch file and an msi file and want to create a single setup file

Comment: msi is created in install shield, and above the command is written which i want to run through batch file

Comment: using a [Winzip self extractor](http://www.winzip.com/fr/prodpagese.html)  appears to be more appropriate in your case, After decompressing the self-extracting Zip files can run an installation program that you provided

Answer (score 0):

There is a free version of installshield for visual studio. It calld indtallshield LE and then you can build setup from within visual studio.
The second option is to compress your msi into rar and then create self extract.